# Jquery sortable not working on iPad (touch device)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-sortable

I’ve had jquery sortable working on a site for a while now.  It works great; however, I’m moving towards more mobile editing via an ipad and I haven’t had any success getting jquery sortable to work via touch devices.

I have looked through other posts on here as well as searched google. I finally found a solution that I semi understood as I’ve never worked much with development towards touch devices.  Below is my code.  The sortable still works correctly on my laptop browser; however, doesn’t work on touch device (ipad)

When I touch the list, it puts a gray background behind the entire `<ul>` list and then if I keep holding, it selects the word where my finger is.  It won’t allow me to drag any of the `<li>` elements around.

Below is my code

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0-alpha.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-alpha.2.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0-alpha.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-alpha.2.min.js"></script>

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
/*!
 * jQuery UI Touch Punch 0.2.3
 *
 * Copyright 2011–2014, Dave Furfero
 * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
 *
 * Depends:
 *  jquery.ui.widget.js
 *  jquery.ui.mouse.js
 */
!function(a){function f(a,b){if(!(a.originalEvent.touches.length>1)){a.preventDefault();var c=a.originalEvent.changedTouches[0],d=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");d.initMouseEvent(b,!0,!0,window,1,c.screenX,c.screenY,c.clientX,c.clientY,!1,!1,!1,!1,0,null),a.target.dispatchEvent(d)}}if(a.support.touch="ontouchend"in document,a.support.touch){var e,b=a.ui.mouse.prototype,c=b._mouseInit,d=b._mouseDestroy;b._touchStart=function(a){var b=this;!e&&b._mouseCapture(a.originalEvent.changedTouches[0])&&(e=!0,b._touchMoved=!1,f(a,"mouseover"),f(a,"mousemove"),f(a,"mousedown"))},b._touchMove=function(a){e&&(this._touchMoved=!0,f(a,"mousemove"))},b._touchEnd=function(a){e&&(f(a,"mouseup"),f(a,"mouseout"),this._touchMoved||f(a,"click"),e=!1)},b._mouseInit=function(){var b=this;b.element.bind({touchstart:a.proxy(b,"_touchStart"),touchmove:a.proxy(b,"_touchMove"),touchend:a.proxy(b,"_touchEnd")}),c.call(b)},b._mouseDestroy=function(){var b=this;b.element.unbind({touchstart:a.proxy(b,"_touchStart"),touchmove:a.proxy(b,"_touchMove"),touchend:a.proxy(b,"_touchEnd")}),d.call(b)}}}(jQuery);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

//$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {



$(document).ready(function(){


$('#sortable').sortable({
   axis: 'y',
    update: function (event, ui) {
        var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');

        // AJAX POST to server
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'inc/refresh_order.php?table=Product_Sections',
            success: function(response) {
             //alert(response);
                var message = "<p>Succesfully updated order of Product Sections</p>";
                $('#message').html(message)
        }
        });
    }
}); 

  $( "#sortable" ).bind( "sortstop", function(event, ui) {
      $('#sortable').listview('refresh');
    });
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
</script>
```

And below is the list (I’m actually generating list via a database query...so this is a random list with styling)

```
<ul id="sortable" class="Sortable_List">
<li id="item-1">item 1</li>
<li id="item-2">item 2</li>
<li id="item-3">item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be great.  Not sure exactly what I did wrong.

Comment: I made a jsfiddle from your code, it works on my phone. Check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/cf5twwqp/

Comment: It’s working on jsfiddle but not on web server.  What could be causing that?  I’ve loaded the most up to date jquery and jquery ui.

Comment: In your head, You are loading jQuery-Mobile AND jQuery-UI, then You may need to know how to handle both libraries together. BTW, You may need additionally to move to the latest JQM 1.4.5.

Comment: I actually took out jquery mobile because it didnt look like the jsfiddle had it loaded.  But with or without it, it still wont move on ipad.   When i click, it highlights the entire table (background only) gray and if I keep holding, it selects the text.  I was able to move items in the jsfiddle though on ipad.  I don't get it. I even updated my jquery and everything to the latest versions to see if there was any issues with that.  I've never been able to get this to work on touch and I'd love to figure this out and get it to work.

Comment: This is a long shot, but if your site runs on SSL you need to load the libraries by https.